# Call parent constructor but keep the reference of the child C#

Tags: c#, constructor, parent-child

I am calling the base constructor but somehow I need to point to the child one back. Take a look at the example bellow:

//Child

```
 public CompanyEventsView(IAggregator aggregator, IRepository<CompanyEvents> repository, int i)
        : base(aggregator, repository, i)
    {

    }
```

//Base

```
  public BaseViewModelFor(IAggregator aggregator, IRepository<TSource> repository, int i) 
    {
        Aggregator = aggregator;
        var source = repository.GetKey(i);
        this.MapFromSourceObject(source); // So "This" here should be pointing to the child class
    }
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Generally speaking, your base class shouldn't depend on child classes at all. The base class should have no knowledge of the child classes whatsoever. Why can't you just do the child constructor stuff in the child constructor?

Answer (score 1):

`this` and `base` do not refer to different instances, they are the same.

If your `MapFromSourceObject` method is defined in the child class, you can cast `this` to the child type like: `(this as CompanyEventsView).MapFromSourceObject(source)`.

But this would defeat the whole point of inheritance.

Maybe define `MapFromSourceObject` as abstract or virtual in the base class?

If your base class depends the implementations of child classes, making the class itself abstract would be a better idea.

Comment: The problem is that the destination (CompanyEventsView) is also generic, therefor i can't point to CompanyEventsView it has ti be a generic pointer if possible something like (this as childClass)

Comment: @NaughtyNinja You still haven't explained why you can't do it in the child's constructor.

Comment: @itsme86 Becuase this parent constructor will be called from more than 100 classes, wanted to create a generic way of doing this rather than repeating the same function each time i create a class

Comment: But you write a `MapFromSourceObject` for each class, already, no?

Comment: @ŞafakGür No it's an extension method pointing to the source class

Comment: If it accepts the base type as argument, you do not need to change anything. `this` keyword already *is* the child instance. `base` and `child` keywords don't get you different instances.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this example helps you a little bit with inheritance:

```
namespace CSharpConsoleApplication.Tests
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    class TemporaryTest
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            Mother<FirstCompanyEvent> firstChild = new FirstChild(new FirstCompanyEvent("this is wrong"));
            firstChild.Print();


            Mother<SecondCompanyEvent> intChild = new SecondChild(new SecondCompanyEvent("you are too young to do this"));
            intChild.Print();
        }
    }


    public abstract class BaseCompanyEvent
    {
        protected string Value { get; private set; }

        public BaseCompanyEvent(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public abstract string GetMessage();
    }

    public class FirstCompanyEvent : BaseCompanyEvent
    {
        public FirstCompanyEvent(string value)
            : base(value)
        { }

        public override string GetMessage()
        {
            return "First born: " + Value;
        }
    }

    public class SecondCompanyEvent : BaseCompanyEvent
    {
        public SecondCompanyEvent(string value)
            : base(value)
        { }

        public override string GetMessage()
        {
            return "Younger brother: " + Value;
        }
    }



    public abstract class Mother<T> where T : BaseCompanyEvent
    {
        protected T CustomEvent { get; private set; }

        public Mother(T customEvent)
        {
            CustomEvent = customEvent;
        }

        public abstract void Print();
    }

    public class FirstChild : Mother<FirstCompanyEvent>
    {
        public FirstChild(FirstCompanyEvent e)
            : base(e)
        { }

        public override void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CustomEvent.GetMessage());
        }
    }

    public class SecondChild : Mother<SecondCompanyEvent>
    {
        public SecondChild(SecondCompanyEvent e)
            : base(e)
        { }

        public override void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CustomEvent.GetMessage());
        }
    }
}
```